# How can I cast IEnumerable<?> to IEnumerable<string>?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, covariance

**This question was completely edited. To see the original one, see the edit history**

---

I think I should explain a little bit of my situation and context of the problem.

I'm inspecting a type for a property annotated with a custom attribute. I then get the value of that property, but as an `object`:

```
IEnumerable<object> propertiesValues = myType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyCustomAttribute)) != null);
```

Once I have these values I want to call my method `Map` on them, which converts them to a different object depending on their type. This is because my database API requires so.

```
foreach(object value in propertiesValues)
{
     object mapped = Map(value);
     // ...
}
```

I need all `IEnumerable<NumberType>` values, to be converted to `IEnumerable<string>`. So my first approach was:

```
public static object Map(object value)
{
    if(value is IEnumerable<short> || value is IEnumerable<int> || ....)
         return ((IEnumerable<object>) value).Cast<string>();
}
```

However, this is throwing a runtime exception, as I cannot cast `IEnumerable<int>` to `IEnumerable<object>` for example.

Comment: I think this is wrong `return ((IEnumerable<object>) value).Cast<string>();` Should it not be `return (IEnumerable<object>) value.Cast<string>();`

Comment: @Tomaltach `value` does not have a `Cast` method (it is just an `object`) so I need to cast it to an `IEnumerable<>`

Comment: `IEnumerable<int> i = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }.AsEnumerable();` then `IEnumerable<object> o = i.Cast<object>().AsEnumerable();` Works. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @RezaAghaei It seems I'm failing at explaining my problem. I just want to cast an `IEnumerable<?>` disguised as an `object`, to `IEnumerable<object>`. Is this possible?

Comment: it is possible, but you are defeating the compiler and making it way harder than it needs to be.

Comment: `Cast<T>` is defined on the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface so just cast to that: `((IEnumerable)value).Cast<string>()`;

Comment: `object i = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }.AsEnumerable();` and then 
`IEnumerable<object> o= (System.Collections.IEnumerable)i).Cast<object>();` Works, Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @MatiasCicero: Your celebration is premature. You simply cannot use the Cast sequence operator to do a representation-changing conversion like that. You can't cast short to string, so you cannot `Cast` an `IE<short>` to an `IE<string>` either.

Comment: What are you doing (or attempting to do) with the strings once you get them? Do they remain strings from then on, e.g. you turn around and write them to a file, or are you using the string as a sort of "serialization" to hold the value so you can cast it/convert it to a type in later processing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The feature you want is called *covariance*, and C# supports it on `IEnumerable<T>` only when the type arguments are both reference types. That is, `IEnumerable<string>` may be converted to `IEnumerable<object>`, but `IEnumerable<int>` may not be so converted.

The reason is: when you get a sequence of strings, those string references are *already* legal object references. But an int only becomes a legal object reference when it is boxed; where does the compiler know to insert the boxing operation? It doesn't, so the conversion is illegal.

To convert an `IEnumerable<int>` to `IEnumerable<object>` you have to do the boxing explicitly via a projection:

```
from number in items select (object)item
```

or

```
items.Select(item => (object) item)
```

That will be `IEnumerable<object>`, and you can then do what you like to that.

Or use the Cast sequence operator

```
items.Cast<object>()
```

which does the same thing.  Or use its query form:

```
from object item in items select item
```

Or simply use the non-generic `IEnumerable`, which gives you a sequence of boxed values if in fact it is a sequence of structs.

I note though that your plan of then casting `IEnumerable<object>` to `IEnumerable<string>` via the `Cast` extension method is doomed to failure. Those items will be boxed ints. Boxed ints cannot be unboxed to string.

It seems like you are fighting the type system here instead of working with it. Perhaps you should describe your real problem, rather than your attempts to do an end-run around the type system to solve it.

Comment: i completely agree with the last sentence.

Comment: I especially agree with the last part about fighting the type system. I just recently sat in on a code review where a fellow developer removed about 15 classes from processing that looked almost exactly like this (processing would inspect the type parameter and then cast and pass to an individual class built for each potential type)

Comment: @moarboilerplate: Right; any time you are interrogating a type parameter for its type argument, your code is no longer *generic*.  Generic code works with all possible types; that's why its called "generic".

Comment: @EricLippert I can't agree. What if my value is obtained via reflection (because I wanted to inspect a property annotated with a custom attribute)? I'd end up with an `object`. I can't apply generics in this situation. What would you recommend? This is exactly my current situation :(

Comment: @MatiasCicero: You've obtained an `object`. You suspect it is a sequence. Ask it if it implements `IEnumerable`. Not the generic version, the non-generic version. Now you have a sequence of objects; do something to those objects.

Comment: @EricLippert Isn't that what RezaAghaei answer suggests?

Comment: @MatiasCicero: No, it is not. I'm saying don't use `IE<T>` *at all*. You note that you are in a world without generics; ok, then *why are you trying to use generics?*

Comment: @EricLippert I tried to reformulate my question the best I could. Please see the edit. I'm bad with my words but I hope this time it is understood better. I really appreciate your enthusiasm in getting this confusion solved.

Comment: @MatiasCicero: I've read your edits, but I still don't understand why `if (value is whatever .... ) return from object item in (IEnumerable)value select value.ToString();` is unacceptable.

Comment: @EricLippert because I only wish to do this with `IEnumerable` containing number data types, not all types. If I check for `IEnumerable` then any `IEnumerable<>` will satisfy the condition.

Comment: @MatiasCicero: That's what the `if` is for.

Comment: @EricLippert My bad. I think this will work, at least it compiles :) Thank you for your time, I know it can be a pain when someone is stubborn as me but I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you do this

```
var source = ... /// IEnumerable<???>
var destination = source.Select(item => item.ToString());
```

You could update `Map`'s signature as well:

```
object Map<TItem, TSource>(TSource source) 
  : where TSource : IEnumerable<TItem>
```

or

```
object Map<TItem>(IEnumerable<TItem> source)
```

Comment: It's not that simple. As I said my `Map` method is a little more complex so I would like to achieve this with that method. I also can't know at runtime what I will pass in to `Map`, hence the `if (type is xx)` conditions

Comment: Still not good enough. `Map` should take any argument, I dont want to create a constraint for `IEnumerable<>`. Also, I don't know the argument's type at compile time, so the constraint is not possible.

Comment: @MatiasCicero i feel then that your design for `Map` is flawed and doing way too much.

Comment: @MatiasCicero you can add overloads to let the compiler help you.

Comment: I don't know the argument's type at compile time. I can't create overloads.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97674/discussion-between-daniel-a-white-and-matias-cicero).